# Protect Images inside my app from copying

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an app that uses copyrighted images that I have permission to use. If a user downloads my app onto their computer using iTunes, they can basically unzip the app file (change filename to add .zip, unzip then show package contents), and see the images.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: or even take a screenshot of the screen and crop the image from there in that case.

Comment: You've come across one of the oldest problems with digital assets:  flawless and effortless copies.  People have been trying for years to combat this problem through various encryption and DRM but it has never been met with complete success.  I always say the best you can do is to make it more trouble than it is worth for the potential violator.  Robotic Cat's suggestion is probably best.

Comment: If bandwidth constraints or load times aren't a problem, you could consider keeping the images server side.

Comment: What about storing them in a .bundle file?  Doesn't that provide some protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to stop this method of accessing the images; the only alternative I can think of is to encrypt the images and store the encrypted files in the app.  Then decrypt the images at runtime.

This won't stop the most determined adversary but would stop people accessing the images without some effort on their part.

Comment: What is your suggested method of encryption?

Comment: iOS has support for AES so use that (search Stackoverflow for examples).  Obviously the key will be in your app and a clever enough opponent will be able to find it but this is beyond most people and will deter them.  But bear in mind that iOS allows easy taking of screenshots so given enough time and effort any large image (even scrollable images) can be obtained by people wanting to copy the image.  The only question is how many obstacles you want to put in the way to deter them.

Comment: Thanks. I am not worried about screenshots, I am just worried about the raw .png files.

Answer (score 0):

A determined adversary will likely be able to get at any files used by an app on a device in their possession.

To defeat a lazy adversary, you might only have to change the file names into something they won't recognize as an image file.  Or change a few bytes containing the file type signature at the beginning of each file, rendering the file corrupt.  Your app can copy them into a temp file and fix the signatures to display.

Apple reportedly encrypts an App store distributed app's compiled C code.  So another possibility might be to embed (portions of) the copyrighted images as hex data inside your source code.

Comment: Another thought I had was to add a password protected .zip file to my app. Then, at first launch, I could unzip it, with the password, and move those files into a directory. Thoughts?

Comment: If you use any encryption or encrypted files, make sure you understand and can comply with any applicable legal CCATS requirements.

Comment: Even if I include a protected .zip file?  What is the process for CCATS?  Never done that before.